# Appengine unit test fail with Objectify - No Class registered

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm getting Class not registered exceptions during unit tests even though it has been registered.

Here is my test:

```
public class BaseObjectifyTest {
    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
            new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig(),
                    new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig());

    Closeable session;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        helper.setUp();
        session = ObjectifyService.begin();
    }

    @Test
    public void testThis() {
        MyEntity test = new MyEntity();
        ObjectifyService.register(MyEntity.class);
        ofy().save().entity(test).now();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        helper.tearDown();
        session.close();
        session = null;
    }
}
```

I've tried doing the ObjectifyService.run() and I get the same result.  Any help would be great!  Would like to write tests and if this doesn't work, I'll have to mock the objectify service.  Objectify 5.1.1

Comment: Wild guess: Your static import of ofy() is not ObjectifyService.ofy

Comment: It was.  Now I'm trying to copy the tests in the Objectify project and using TestObjectifyService.ofy - still not working

Comment: A stack trace would help - it probably has to do with test execution order and static/property initialisation order.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys.  I found the problem.  I was using JUnit and TestNG together and the setup for the tests were not being executed.  Everything is all good now.

Comment: @Patrick Add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using JUnit and TestNG togeth and the setup for the tests were not being executed.